# How to extract image link from Google Spreadsheet cell

Tags: google-sheets

The text below is coming from an external source RSS using Zapier and it is stored in a google sheets cell, how can I extract the image link specifically inside the src tag?

```
<p><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-20168" src="https://jd3sljkvzi-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Ra_Adagio_Splash_1000px.jpg" alt="" width="1000" height="563" srcset="https://jd3sljkvzi-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Ra_Adagio_Splash_1000px.jpg 1000w, https://jd3sljkvzi-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Ra_Adagio_Splash_1000px-300x169.jpg 300w, https://jd3sljkvzi-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Ra_Adagio_Splash_1000px-768x432.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px" /></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `REGEX` It is possible. For example,the

> image link specifically inside the src tag

can be extracted by

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(https://\S+)"&CHAR(34))
```